# OpenWrt Linino - Enable syntax highlighting in nano

Tags: openwrt, syntax-highlighting, nano

I'm running Linino on my Arduino Yun and I'm trying to enable Python syntax highlighting when using nano.  I've looked under `/usr/share` but there's no `nano` folder there.

Ctrl+G from inside nano just gives me the error "[Sorry, support for this function has been disabled]".

Is there any way to install the full version of nano or another way to enable syntax highlighting?